# Python and c++11 for swig : how enable c++11

Tags: python, c++11, swig

I'm trying to use swig to using shared library with python. I'm not very experimented with c++ but I've make a first test with a simple object (in c++) and that's working good.

Now I try to make it work with a bigger project that already compile under Linux (and Windows). But I can't make it work.

Here is what I've try :

My CMakeLists for Swig :

```
project(elecswig)

include_directories(${COREALPI_DIR}/include)
include_directories(/usr/include/c++/4.9)

find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})
if (NOT MSVC)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
endif()

find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

set_source_files_properties(src/elec.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
set_source_files_properties(src/elec.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall")

link_directories(${COREALPI_LIBRARY})

swig_add_module(elecswig python src/elec.i)

swig_link_libraries(elecswig
    ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
    elec
)
```

And my elec.i for Swig who's call a .h with namespace:

```
#define __linux__ 1
#define __GNUC__ 4

%module elecswig
%{
    #include "ca/elec/model/modelvoltagedrop.h"
%}

%include "ca/elec/model/modelvoltagedrop.h"
```

And when I try to compile to get my Python Lybrary I've the following error :

```
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32: Error: CPP #error "This file requires compiler and library support for the \
ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.". Use the -cpperraswarn option to continue swig processing.
/usr/include/c++/4.9/cstring:41: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/string:38: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stringfwd.h:39: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/memoryfwd.h:48: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:59: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/functexcept.h:39: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:37: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ext/type_traits.h:34: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/move.h:33: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/concept_check.h:35: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:64: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/cwchar:41: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/allocator.h:46: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++allocator.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/localefwd.h:39: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/localefwd.h:40: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++locale.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/iosfwd:38: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/cctype:41: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
[...]
/usr/include/c++/4.9/cstdlib:41: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/utility:68: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ctime:41: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ctime:42: Error: Unable to find 'time.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/iomanip:38: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/numeric:60: Error: Unable to find 'bits/c++config.h'
elecswig/CMakeFiles/_elecswig.dir/build.make:53: recipe for target 'elecswig/elecPYTHON_wrap.cxx' failed
make[2]: *** [elecswig/elecPYTHON_wrap.cxx] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:75: recipe for target 'elecswig/CMakeFiles/_elecswig.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [elecswig/CMakeFiles/_elecswig.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:75: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems that he can't find many files.h but I mostly have the c++11 error.

I've trying to set Flags in CMake but it seem no change anything.

If you can help me please ?

I can provide more information if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Something is weird with your compiler/cmake setup if you need to write `include_directories(/usr/include/c++/4.9)` explicitly.

Comment: I can't however manage to reproduce your problem, I've got almost an identical CMake file other than that noted change which works. I think your compiler itself may be broken in some weird way given the other errors.

Comment: The strange thing is I can compile this project (with c++11 flag) without using swig... so why when I use swig he tell me that. I've try on another machine and I get the same error.

Comment: Make a complete *minimal* example that reproduces the problem and then others can reproduce the problem. I can't reproduce your problem from what you've posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of tests, I found reason why it was not working. In the CMakeLists :

```
set_source_files_properties(src/elec.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall")
```

include all libraries and dependencies, anyway of compiler use. And if you have 2 version of libstdc++ and gcc/g++, it seems he can't find the good libraries to link / use.

If I remove it, CMake does the job. I have no more `unable to find` or `c++11` problems.

I've to use g++-5 to make it work too (4.9 seems miss some features for c++11) and add the good namespace and include.

Now I've access to my shared library in Python.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how to properly enable C++11 support for SWiG modules. Using "-std=c++11" is a work-around that doesn't work everywhere. cmake has a generic mechanism to require C++11, by setting a target property. Given the title of the question, a good answer would specify how to solve this generically.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, to answer the question that is asked in the title of this post (which is different from the problem the original author actually had):

Use this declaration instead of setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`:

```
set_property(TARGET ${SWIG_MODULE_elecswig_REAL_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED 11)
```

Comment: I've tried your solution with another project, but cmake still warn about this... `${SWIG_MODULE_elecswig_REAL_NAME}` seems empty for me

Comment: What you call SWIG_MODULE_elecswig_REAL_NAME ?